# How can you determine if a function is heavy tailed from its characteristic function?

Tags: poisson-distribution, heavy-tailed, cauchy-distribution, characteristic-function

The question is given as follow:

Let $N$ have a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$. $X_i$ is Cauchy distribution with mode 0 and and scaling parameter $1$.

Find the characteristic function for $Z = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} X_i$. Using this representation, show that $Z$ is heavy tailed.

For the first part, the characteristic function of $X_i$ is $\exp(-|t|)$. The probability generating function of Poisson distribution is $Es^N = e^{\lambda(s-1)}$ Hence

$$E e^{itZ} = e^{\lambda(e^{-i|t|}-1)}$$

It is unclear to me how this means that $Z$ is heavy tailed.

By heavy tailed, we mean that $E e^{\tilde{t}Z}$ does not exist for any $t>0$. so does that mean we set $t = -i\tilde{t}$ in the function for the characteristic function and realise this is not a real function. (so, does that mean if the mgf exists, it must be be an analytic continuation of the characteristic function?)

Comment: You don't have the correct definition of heavy tailed.  I edited your post to make it more readable.

Comment: what is the correct definition? i thoguht it means the mgf does not exist? @MichaelChernick

Comment: For the def of heavy-tailed see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/530724/definition-of-heavy-tailed-distribution