# Definition of heavy-tailed distribution

Tags: probability, intuition, power-law, heavy-tailed

I'm reading about heavy-tailed distributions, the definition states that:

> The distribution of a real-valued random variable $X$ is said to have a **heavy right tail** if the probabilities $\mathbb{P}(X > x)$ decay more slowly than those of any exponential distribution, i.e., if: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\lambda x} \cdot \mathbb{P}(X > x) = \infty,$$
> for every $\lambda > 0$.

Can anyone please intuitively explain the mathematical expression? As for the first part of the definition, it was understood. However, I'm struggling to connect it with the mathematical definition.

Comment: Hint: Assume $X$ has an exponential distribution and compute the limit. Then try with $X$ a Pareto distribution, then with $X$ a Weibull distribution. Then make comparison plots of the (log) tail probabilities ...

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168851/example-of-heavy-tailed-distribution-that-is-not-long-tailed,

Comment: For the exponential distribution I found: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\lambda x} \cdot \mathbb{P}(X > x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\lambda x} \cdot e^{-\lambda x} = 1.$$

Comment: For the Pareto distribution I found: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\lambda x} \cdot \mathbb{P}(X > x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\lambda x} \cdot (x_m/x)^{\alpha} = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\lambda x}/x^{\alpha} \cdot x_m^{\alpha} = \infty \cdot x_m^{\alpha} = \infty.$$

Comment: Are the demonstrations correct @kjetil b halvorsen? And thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @kjetil b halvorsen, I'm really embarassed to ask you again. I'm incapable of reaching $\lambda - \mu$. I don't how to go from $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\lambda x} \cdot e^{-\mu x}$: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\lambda x} \cdot \mathbb{P}(X > x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\lambda x} \cdot e^{-\mu x} = ...$$ I really apologize for the additional question.

Comment: Sorry I was to fast. So  the limit with details. $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\lambda x}\cdot e^{-\mu x}=\lim e^{(\lambda-\mu) x}=\begin{cases} 1&\mu=\lambda \\ \infty & \lambda>\mu \\ 0 & \lambda < \mu \end{cases}$. So, since it is **not** $\infty$ for all $\lambda$, the conclusion that the exponential is not heavy-tailed follows.

Comment: Really well understood. Thank you so much for your time and patience!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a *fixed* $\lambda>0$, we can rewrite the product as a fraction, so we can see the complementary cdf (right tail) of $Y_\lambda\sim Exp(\lambda)$:

$$  P(Y_\lambda >x)=e^{-\lambda x}. $$

We have:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\lambda x} \cdot P(X > x)  = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{P(X > x)}{ P(Y_\lambda>x)} = \infty.$$

This [infinite limit at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_at_infinity) means that: for *every* $M>0$ *there is an* $N_M>0$ such that
$$ \frac{P(X > x)}{ P(Y_\lambda >x)} >M \; \;\left[\iff P(X>x)> M P(Y_\lambda >x) \right]$$

for *all* $x>N_M.$ That is for any given positive factor, for sufficiently high $x$, $X$'s right tail (starting at $x$) is bigger than $Y_\lambda$'s right tail (starting at $x$) scaled by the given factor.

In particular, for, say, $M=1$ there is $N_1> 0$ such that

$$ P(X>x)> P(Y_\lambda>x) $$

for *all* $x>N_1$.

This has to hold for *all* $\lambda > 0$ values.

Comment: Excellent explanation @ir7. Thank you so much!